# how to get a response to know if the user has actually tweeted

Tags: twitter

i have a webpage. on it, i have added a twitter tweet button, available here

http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

using this, the user is able to connect via twitter, and also post tweets. another thing possible is that user clicks on the button, maybe even logs in with twitter, but closes the popup without tweeting.

now, i need to get some kind of response to know when the user has actually tweeted. if the user has tweeted, i have to display a message on my native webpage saying 'thank you for tweeting' and IF POSSIBLE, the tweet text that he tweeted.

any ideas?